# using a group by in linq to select aggregated records

Tags: c#, linq, collections, group-by

The linq collection is made of a SearchResult object.

SearchResult contains: id (number), categoryName (string)

I would like to select into a new collection using linq all the aggregated categories (that is, if there is at least one search result with a category A then include category A in the collection).

If possible to sort the results alphabetically.

Example:

Search results:

1, Computers

2, IT

3, Finance

4, Finance

5, News

6, Weather

7, IT

8, Fashion

The resulting collection: (Computers, Fashion, Finance, IT, News, Weather).

Here's what I've got so far:

SearchResultsCollection is IEnumerable

```
var categs = SearchResultsCollection.GroupBy(f => GetCategory(f))
           .Select(GetCategory(f)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `GroupBy` in this case, but it's not necessary since you are projecting to a primitive property anyway - group first, select the group key and order:

```
var categs = SearchResultsCollection.GroupBy(f => f.categoryName)
                                    .Select(g => g.Key)
                                    .OrderBy(f => f)
                                    .ToList();
```

Or easier using [`Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx):

```
var categs = SearchResultsCollection.Select(f=> f.categoryName)
                                    .Distinct()
                                    .OrderBy(c => c)
                                    .ToList();
```